# JQGrid is displaying Date as a long number and not able to convert using formatoption

Tags: spring, jqgrid

My application is developed using Spring MVC + Hibernate + JQGrid and MySQL as database. In one of the table = 'cmpmst' there are two fields which are dates, and I am passing these to jqgrid using JSON. All other fields are displayed correctly, but date fields are not displayed as proper date format which I want it as 'dd/mm/yyyy' format. Instead, it is displayed as long number as '1427740200000'.

So, I have taken help from the web and applied formatoption as "formatter : 'date', formatoptions : {newformat: 'ShortDate'}", but after application of this format option, now I see it as "NaN/NaN/NaN". I am working on finding solution since last 15 days by taking help from web, but not able to resolve the issue, please help.

My colmodel for the JQGrid is as below:

```
colModel:[
                {name:'cmpcode',index:'cmpcode', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                {name:'cmpdescr',index:'cmpdescr', width:100, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                {name:'cmpfybegin',index:'cmpfybegin', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{date: true}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}, formatter : 'date', formatoptions : {newformat: 'ShortDate'}},
                {name:'cmpfyend',index:'cmpfyend', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30, maxlength: 60}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}}
            ],
```

My controller code is as below:

```
public ModelAndView doEdit(HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {
     Byte cmpcode = 0;
     String companydescr = null, oper = null;

     Date companyfybegin = Date.from(Instant.EPOCH), companyfyend = Date.from(Instant.EPOCH);
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


     Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
     while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
         String s = paramNames.nextElement();
         if("cmpcode".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
             cmpcode = Byte.parseByte(request.getParameter("cmpcode"));
         }else if("cmpdescr".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
             companydescr = request.getParameter("cmpdescr");
         }else if("cmpfybegin".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
             companyfybegin = formatter.parse(request.getParameter("cmpfybegin"));
         }else if("cmpfyend".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
             companyfyend = formatter.parse(request.getParameter("cmpfyend"));
         }else if("oper".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
             oper = request.getParameter("oper");
         }
     }
    Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
     if("edit".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
         CompanyMst companymst = new CompanyMst();
         companymst.setCmpcode(cmpcode);
         companymst.setCmpdescr(companydescr);
         companymst.setCmpfybegin(companyfybegin);
         companymst.setCmpfyend(companyfyend);
         companymstService.updateCompanyMst(companymst);
     }else if("add".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
         CompanyMst companymst = companymstService.getCompanyMst(cmpcode);
         if(companymst == null){
            companymst = new CompanyMst();
            companymst.setCmpcode(cmpcode);
            companymst.setCmpdescr(companydescr);
            companymst.setCmpfybegin(companyfybegin);
            companymst.setCmpfyend(companyfyend);
            companymstService.saveCompanyMst(companymst);
         }else{
             throw new RuntimeException();
         }
     }else if("del".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
         companymstService.deleteCompanyMst(cmpcode);
     }
     return new ModelAndView("admin/companymstmgmt",model);
 }
```

If anything more needs to be uploaded, please let me know.

I am using JQGrid version 4.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above error by implementing following in colmodel for JQGrid

```
                    {name:'cmpfybegin',index:'cmpfybegin', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{date: true}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}, formatter : 'date', formatoptions : {newformat: 'd/m/Y'}},
                {name:'cmpfyend',index:'cmpfyend', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{date:true}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'},formatter : 'date', formatoptions : {newformat: 'd/m/Y'}}
```

In addition to that I have also amended the entity class as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cmpmst", catalog = "nioerpj")
public class CompanyMst implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Byte cmpcode;
    private String cmpdescr;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date cmpfybegin;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date cmpfyend;
```

Now, it is working as expected.